# Find the directional derivatives of a function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Consider the function $f : R^2 → R$ given by
>
> $$
> f(x, y) =
> \begin{cases}
> \begin{matrix}
> \frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2} & \mathrm{if}\ (x, y) \ne(0, 0)\\
> 0 & \mathrm{if}\ (x, y) = (0, 0) \\
> \end{matrix}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> Using the definition, compute the directional derivative $\partial_uf(0,0) $ for
>   all directions $u=(u_1, u_2)\ne (0, 0)$. [Hint: Consider the cases $u_2 \ne 0$
>   and $u_2 = 0$ separately, and use that $\partial _uf(0, 0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(hu_1,hu_2)−f(0,0)}{h}$.]

Here is my solution:

We know that $f(0,0)=0$, we can rewrite the formula for the directional derivative as $$\partial _uf(0, 0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(hu_1,hu_2)}{h}$$

We have that in the function, $x$ is denoted by $hu_1$ and $y$ is denoted by $hu_2$.

We now look at each case, in terms of the original function.

**Case 1:** We have that $u_2=0$,

$$\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{((hu_1)^2(h\cdot 0))}{h ((hu_1)^4+(hu_2)^2)}\right) = 0$$

**Case 2:** We have that $u_2\ne0$,

$$\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{((hu_1)^2(hu_2))}{h ((hu_1)^4+(hu_2)^2)}\right) = \lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{h^3(u_1^2u_2)}{h^3(h^2 u_1^4+u_2^2)}\right) = \lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{u_1^2u_2}{h^2 u_1^4+u_2^2}\right)$$

Solving as $h\to0$ we see that the $\lim\to \frac{u_1^2}{u_2}$.

Therefore the directional derivatives for $\partial_uf(0,0)$ in the direction $u=(u_1,0)$ is $0$. The directional derivative in the direction $u=(u_1,u_2)$ is $\frac{u_1^2}{u_2}$.

**Is this solution correct? How can I improve this answer in general?**

Comment: Your solution is not correct. There were lots of mistakes/typos in there. I have edited the derivation until the line in Case 2. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have edited the question now, the problem lies at the end of the line in case 2:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{u_1^2u_2}{h^2 u_1^4+u_2^2}\right) = \frac{u_1^2u_2}{u_2^2} = \frac{u_1^2}{u_2}$$

Hence $\partial_u f(0,0) = \frac{u_1^2}{u_2}$.

Have a look at these plots to get an inuitive understanding of the behaviour of the function near $(0,0)$. There you can also tell why it is sensible to distinguish between the case of $u_2 = 0$ ($=: y$ in the plot) and $u_2 \neq 0$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With $$u_2 \neq 0$$ it is

$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0 } \frac{{u_1 ^2 u_2 }}
{{h^2 u_1 ^4  + u_2 ^2 }} = \frac{{u_1 ^2 }}
{{u_2 }}
$$

Answer (score 1):

There are some typos ! The quotient $\frac{f(hu_1,hu_2)}{h}$ is given by

$$\frac{f(hu_1,hu_2)}{h}= \frac{u_1^2u_2}{h^2u_1^4+u_2^2}.$$

If $u_2=0$, then $\frac{f(hu_1,hu_2)}{h}=0 \to 0$ as $h \to 0.$

If $u_2 \ne  0$, then $\frac{f(hu_1,hu_2)}{h} \to \frac{u_1^2}{u_2}$ as $h \to 0.$

Comment: Ooops, a typo, thanks !